# Blank lines in align environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, amsmath, align

Is there a way to insert a blank line between two equations in
align environment?

From what I understand a blank line is interpreted as `\par` and
`\par` is not allowed in align. Can I disable this "feature" in
align environment?

Reason:

I like my code to be in 80 column format. So when I hit
M-q (fill-paragraph) without blank lines, the code looks like this:

```
\begin{align}
  \min \sum_{k \in K} \sum_{(i,j) \in A} c_{ij} x_{ij}^k + \sum_{(i,j)
    \in A} f_{ij} y_{ij} \\ \sum_{j \in V_i^+} x_{ij}^k - \sum_{j \in
    V_i^-} x_{ji}^k = \begin{cases} d^k & \text{si } i = O(k) \\ -d^k
    & \text{si } i = D(k) \\ 0 & \text{sinon} \end{cases} & \quad
  \quad \forall i \in V, \; \forall k \in K \\ \sum_{k \in K} x_{ij}^k
  \le u_{ij} y_{ij} & \quad \quad \forall (i,j) \in A
\end{align}
```

instead of this:

```
\begin{align}
  \min \sum_{k \in K} \sum_{(i,j) \in A} c_{ij} x_{ij}^k + \sum_{(i,j)
    \in A} f_{ij} y_{ij} \\

  \sum_{j \in V_i^+} x_{ij}^k - \sum_{j \in V_i^-} x_{ji}^k
  = \begin{cases} d^k & \text{si } i = O(k) \\ -d^k & \text{si } i =
    D(k) \\ 0 & \text{sinon} \end{cases} & \quad \quad \forall i \in
  V, \; \forall k \in K \\

  \sum_{k \in K} x_{ij}^k \le u_{ij} y_{ij} & \quad \quad \forall
  (i,j) \in A
\end{align}
```

which is easier (for me) to read and edit.

Comment: Remark, there's a hack in [Ignore blank lines in math mode - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276072/ignore-blank-lines-in-math-mode) to modify LaTeX to allow these blank lines, but generally it's not recommended.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

put a `%` in those lines and everything will be fine for `amsmath` and for you

Comment: Or put the "\\" that you already have on the lines that you want to be empty.

Comment: which then also will be numbered ...

Comment: @Herbert: Maybe you misunderstood Bruno? He means _moving_ the existing "\\", not _adding_ new ones.

Comment: @Bruno: Does this solve the "M-q-problem"?

Comment: @Hendrik: It depends on the editor. If it is emacs, then my solution does not work (I forgot to test), whereas Herbert's works.

Comment: @Hendrik: Yes, with %--------- (80 columns long)

Comment: so how do i have an unnumbered empty line inbetwen two equation lines with numbers?