# Error in align environment - runaway argument?

Tags: equations, errors, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blank lines in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10355/blank-lines-in-align-environment)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
\ce{K_a} & = \frac{\ce{[H3O+][A^-]}}{\ce{[HA]}} \\

\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

gives

```
 Runaway argument?
 \ce {K_a} & = \frac {\ce {[H3O+][A^-]}}{\ce {[HA]}} \\ 
! Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8
```

?

Comment: You can't have a blank line in the `align*` (or `align`) environment, or indeed in display math.

Comment: I vaguely remember now!  Thanks!  Post your comment as a solution and I will accept it.

Comment: @Joseph: I think this question is neither "too localized"  nor an "exact duplicate". Please convert your commnet into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep Done, in an enlarged form

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't have a blank line in the `align*` (or `align`) environment, or indeed in display math. Thus you want

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
  \ce{K_a} & = \frac{\ce{[H3O+][A^-]}}{\ce{[HA]}} \\
  %
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
  \ce{K_a} & = \frac{\ce{[H3O+][A^-]}}{\ce{[HA]}} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

(I've used `amsmath` directly, rather than load it *via* `siunitx`, to minimise the example.)

Comment: Using `amsmath` to "minimise" the example in what sense?

Comment: @ptrcao The `siunitx` package is not necessary to see the problem, you only need to ensure that `align*` is defined. Thus I'm loading the minimum number of packages to show the problem. (Add `\listfiles` to the original and to my example, and the list of packages will be much shorter for the later.)