# Why does leaving a blank line in displaymath mode cause an error during compilation?

Tags: errors, matrices, syntax

When I compile the following code everything runs with no issues:

```
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
2 & 3
\end{matrix} \right]
\quad
\left[ \begin{matrix}
2 & 3
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
```

However, when I add a blank line to improve readability, the compiler outputs an error about some missing $:

```
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
2 & 3
\end{matrix} \right]

\quad

\left[ \begin{matrix}
2 & 3
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
```

What can be causing this error? It seems to me there is nothing wrong with the syntax.

By the way, in case it might be useful, I am compiling with the command `pdflatex beamer.tex`.

Comment: You already know that an empty line in LaTeX means the end/beginning of a new paragraph... But what about math mode? Do you expect there to start a new math environment in its own line? Then just break the environment into two environments... by closing the previous and opening the next... (This is what compiler understood and was looking for the missing `$`) Display math doesn't have paragraphs... Inline math also doesn't have paragraphs... Also... what the \quad supposed to do there ... (You may comment out the empty lines if you need them for some reason)

Comment: I think the two matrices are supposed to appear on the same line with a quad-space in between.

Comment: @koleygr To be quite honest, I was testing the different matrix environments. But I imagine using it, for example, to display matrices side by side after you apply row operations on them. And the spaces were added to visually separate each matrix.

Comment: If you want to add empty lines for readability, put `%` at the beginning of the empty line. TeX will completely ignore it then. Unrelated to the problem, have a look at [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: This is by design and built in to tex-the-program to stop  a missing math delimiter destroying the rest of the document.

Comment: Unrelated, but `amsmath` defines a `bmatrix` environment, which results in a shorter code.

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

You wrote,

> It seems to me there is nothing wrong with the syntax.

Actually, something *is* wrong with the syntax: All-blank lines are *not allowed* in math mode -- both inline math mode and display math mode.

For more on this subject, please see the earlier postings [Blank lines in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10355/5001) and [Error in align environment - runaway argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30012/5001). Aside: The `align` environment is a displaymath-mode environment.

A separate plea: Don't use `$$` in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate display-math mode. For more information on this subjecct, please see the postings [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Comment: Actually, blank lines are not allowed in *any* math environment, whether display or in-line.  As @DavidCarlisle said in a comment, this is by design: since math cannot extend across paragraphs, the error is reported if any paragraph break occurs while a math expression is incomplete.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Many thanks for this comment. I've updated my answer accordingly.