# Align Environment and Spacing

Tags: spacing, equations, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blank lines in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10355/blank-lines-in-align-environment)

When I put a blank line between a line of text and the `align` environment, it will add two blank lines instead. It seems that the `align` environment automatically adds a set of blank lines. I don't want two sets of blank lines, but this makes my code very hard to read. Compare (the 'correct way')

```
\begin{align*}
L\frac{di}{dt} + Ri = EU(t) \\
i(0) = 0
\end{align*}
In Heaviside's operator notation, this is 
\begin{align*}
pLi + Ri &= EU(t)\\
i &= \frac{E}{pL + R}U(t)
\end{align*}
```

and

```
\begin{align*}
L\frac{di}{dt} + Ri = EU(t) \\
i(0) = 0
\end{align*}

In Heaviside's operator notation, this is 

\begin{align*}
pLi + Ri &= EU(t)\\
i &= \frac{E}{pL + R}U(t)
\end{align*}
```

This may seem trivial but in a large document it's really hard to read the first example and relatively easy to read the second.

Is there a way to change this, e.g. with a `\renewcommand`?

By the way, is there an easier way of putting code on this site besides hitting space bar 4 times for each line? I tried HTML tags but they don't work.

Comment: For readability of your source file, you can simply put a comment character (`%`) to separate the lines in your first example.  For highlighting code in tex.sx posts, you can select all the code and then click on the `{}` icon.

Comment: The blank line tells `TeX` to start a new paragraph; the behaviour you are seeing is to be expected. You are not seeing two blank lines, but are seeing a paragraph skip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the comment sign `%` instead of a blank line.

```
\begin{align*}
L\frac{di}{dt} + Ri = EU(t) \\
i(0) = 0
\end{align*}
%
In Heaviside's operator notation, this is 
%
\begin{align*}
pLi + Ri &= EU(t)\\
i &= \frac{E}{pL + R}U(t)
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Fantastic, this is a much better solution than I anticipated.

Comment: This only removes the top line for me, [not the bottom one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39685/different-spacing-around-equation-and-align).