# Different spacing around equation and align

Tags: spacing, equations, align

In my document, I use `align` and `equation`, depending on the length of the equation. They are spaced differently, as you can see on the picture below.

I [read that comments in the empty lines would help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36267/align-environment-and-spacing), but it only removes the top blank line.

How can I get the `equation` and the `align` environment to look alike in spacing?

[image]

```
Dieses $\beta$ ist der kritische Winkel, bei dem (solange man vorsichtig zieht) nichts passiert. Ist das Drehmoment positiv, rotiert das Jojo im Uhrzeigersin, also im negativen Sinn, oder nach rechts.

Für eine Rotation nach rechts gilt:

\begin{align*}
0 &< R_2 \cos(\beta) - R_1 \\
\frac{R_1}{R_2}  &< \cos(\beta) \\
\end{align}

Der Kosinus ist nur im Interval $\left(- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ positiv. $\beta$ muss also zwischen dem positiven und negativen kritischen Winkel liegen:

\begin{equation*}
\arccos \left( \frac{R_1}{R_2} \right) > |\beta|, \quad \beta \in (-\pi, \pi]
\end{equation}

Für eine Rotation nach links muss der Winkelbetrag größer sein, man zieht entweder steil nach oben, steil nach unten oder direkt nach links.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the document `mathmode` by Herbert Voß you find on page 31 the following hint:

> There are four predefined lengths, which control the vertical
>   whitespace of displayed formulas:
>
> ```
> \abovedisplayskip=12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt
> \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt plus 3pt
> \belowdisplayskip=12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt
> \belowdisplayshortskip=7pt plus 3pt minus 4pt
> ```
>
> The short skips are used if the formula starts behind the end of the
>   foregoing last line. Only for demonstration the shortskips are set to
>   0pt in the following examples and the normal skips to 20pt without any
>   glue:

In this contents you have to know that `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip` are working only for `equation` and not `align`.

The additional space you are mentioned based on the blank lines before and after the `align` environment. You can remove or comment these lines.

Your second error based on the line break. The last line of the environment `align` don't need a `\\`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
Dieses $\beta$ ist der kritische Winkel, bei dem (solange man vorsichtig zieht) nichts passiert. Ist das Drehmoment positiv, rotiert das Jojo im Uhrzeigersin, also im negativen Sinn, oder nach rechts.

Für eine Rotation nach rechts gilt:
%
\begin{align*}
0 &< R_2 \cos(\beta) - R_1 \\
\frac{R_1}{R_2}  &< \cos(\beta)
\end{align*}
%
Der Kosinus ist nur im Interval $\left(- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ positiv. $\beta$ muss also zwischen dem positiven und negativen kritischen Winkel liegen:
%
\begin{equation*}
\arccos \left( \frac{R_1}{R_2} \right) > |\beta|, \quad \beta \in (-\pi, \pi]
\end{equation*}
%
Für eine Rotation nach links muss der Winkelbetrag größer sein, man zieht entweder steil nach oben, steil nach unten oder direkt nach links.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, removing the \\ (I guess it was a copy & paste error) and adding the `%` make it look nice now. Thanks!

Comment: Meinst du das inhaltlich? Allerdings ist doch $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$, von daher muss ich dort ein offenes Interval nehmen, oder?

Comment: This is a great answer I gave you +1 a few days ago. I would like to know why this is going to work only in `equation`? If I want to add more whitespace above and below `align` what can I do?

Comment: @Adam: Then you have to use `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`