# Ignore blank lines in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I have the generated LaTeX code with mathematical expressions. My problem is these generated expressions can contain some blank lines which pdflatex can't compile. Code is generated by custom application and I can't change its output. I have to handle it by some post-processing application which removed these lines or directly in LaTeX.

Code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[

       x^{2} + \sqrt{7} - \frac{3}{7}

    \]

    \(x^{2}

    \)
\end{document}
```

So my question is: Is there a way to ignore or replace this blank lines in LaTeX? Thanks.

Comment: Put a comment (`%`) symbol in these blank lines.

Comment: I have edited my post. Application is custom, I can't change its output.

Comment: the restriction regarding blank lines in math is built into tex.  it would be difficult to get around it without a change in tex, which isn;t about to happen.

Comment: It is possible but the generator is _broken_ If it is maintained at all you should try to get it fixed. If you can not fix it, rather than corrupt the tex with fragile work-arounds I would post process teh generated code with perl or python or sed etc, and remove blank lines before adding to the tex document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\let\par\relax}
\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\let\par\relax}

\begin{document}
    \[

       x^{2} + \sqrt{7} - \frac{3}{7}

    \]

    \(x^{2}

    \)
\end{document}
```

but this won't work for the `amsmath` alignment environments.

A version that seems to work also with `align` and `gather`; however, there might be unexpected effects.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\let\par\relax}
\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\let\par\relax}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd[\long]{\collect@@body}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\push@begins}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\addto@envbody}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\align@}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\gather@}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\measure@}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\gmeasure@}{}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}

       x^{2} + \sqrt{7} - \frac{3}{7}

    \end{align}
    \begin{gather}

       x^{2} + \sqrt{7} - \frac{3}{7}

    \end{gather}

    \(x^{2}

    \)
\end{document}
```