# Empty line in mathematical environment without compiling errors

Tags: environments

I would like to make sure that: If I'm in an environment to write mathematical formulas, for example the environment

```
\begin{align}
x^2
\end{align}
```

and by chance I write

```
\begin{align}
x^2
**(this is an empty row)**
\end{align}
```

the code gives me no error while compiling.

Comment: This will give an error for me.

Comment: Well, there is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276072/82917 , but you really shouldn't...

Comment: unless you are using luatex it is a syntax error, so you  are asking for tex not to report errors which is not in general possible. (You could try to locally redefine blank line not to end a paragraph, but that is likely to break other things)

Comment: The rationale for not allowing blank lines in math is explained here: [Blank lines in an equation and some other similar function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315200)